# how to change the image automatically in view pager when it reaches the last image it should come to the first image automatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am now implementing the view pager and i want to continuously change the image one by one automatically for a particular periods of time may be once in 5 ms .

I also have to manually allow the user to swipe the images (it is working properly)

But the image is not automatically changing and when it reaches the last image it should come to the first image automatically

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == strImages.length-1) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                intro_images.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
        timer .schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 500, 3000);
```

I used above code but it does not work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this add `addOnPageChangeListener` to your `viewPager` like this

```
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == strImages.length-1) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            intro_images.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

**or for auto change page try this create a time task like this**

```
Timer timer;
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, 3000); // delay*/

 private class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

@Override
public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

           if (current < strImages.size()) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                    current += 1;
                } else {

                    current = 0;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);

                }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: i have tried all these but it does not meet my requirement can i expect some new answers 

i have seen this answer and tried but no use it does not change

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem exactly @Nilesh Rathod

Answer (score 3):

**The below code is to get the last position and to scroll to the 1st position:**

```
 pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
 {
            @Override

      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (position == Yourlist.size()-1) {
                  pager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
                  pager.setCurrentItem(position++,true);


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

**The below code is For automatic change picture in every 10s using CountDown Timer:**

```
 - First you have to declare one array,which will contain your
   images,then after you have to use below code.

int i=0;


new CountDownTimer(1000,1000)
 {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    iV.setImageDrawable(sdk.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(array[i]));
                    i++;
                    if(i== array.length-1) {i=0;}
                    start();
                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: This is a great idea where the process goes perfectly but the image is not changing , how ever thanks for helping and good approach  @komal akhani

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the combination of `Handler` and `TimerTask` for this, You can use simple `Handler` like this using `Handler.postDelayed`

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int totalCount = intro_images.getAdapter().getCount();
        int currentItem = intro_images.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentItem == (totalCount - 1)) {
            currentItem = 0;
        } else {
            currentItem = currentItem + 1;
        }
        intro_images.setCurrentItem(currentItem, true);

        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    handler.postDelayed(Update, 500);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(Update);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good idea which i have tried and the image was not changing but thanks @Muthukrishnan Rajendran

Answer (score 0):

just add listener to your viewpager to get the last position and to scroll to the 1st position.

```
vp.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        if(position==yourlist.length){
                            vp.setCurrentItem(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: when i swipe it comes properly but i need this to done automatically for example i have 10 images , all the 10 images should be changing automatically once in 5 ms when it reaches the 10th image then it should come to the first one and start doing the same this is what i need exactly

Answer (score -1):

```
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
```