# Proper implementation of ViewPager2 in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, androidx, android-viewpager2

I came to know about [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha01) and tried to implement it, but didn't find any proper example.

Can anyone tell me how can I use it.

I am looking for proper usage, not an example.

Comment: Here is explanation and example check it : http://michaelevans.org/blog/2019/02/07/hands-on-with-viewpager2/

Comment: Whoever given close votes for `recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource` Please read carefully that I am not looking for example.

Comment: There is an official sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-viewpager2

Comment: appreciated question, look like Blog :D

Comment: @NikunjParadva Answer of Nilesh Rathod is much appreciated and also looks like blog post. The question is just simple.

Comment: Here's an article of implementation https://t.ly/3qgj

Answer (score 294, accepted):

## UPDATE 7

Check : [Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration)

Check : [Create swipe views with tabs using ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2)

## UPDATE 6

Check out [my  answer if you want to implement Carousel using View Pager2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056129/7666442)

## UPDATE 5

> How to use TabLayout with ViewPager2

**SAMPLE CODE**

Use below **`dependencies`**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta02'
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

> XMl layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/tabs"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        viewpager.adapter = AppViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewpager, object : TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback {
            override fun onConfigureTab(tab: TabLayout.Tab, position: Int) {
                // Styling each tab here
                tab.text = "Tab $position"
            }
        }).attach()


    }
}
```

> **OUTPUT**

[TabLayout with ViewPager2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WysV.png)

From Docs

[**`ViewPager2`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)

> New features

- Right-to-left (RTL) layout support
- Vertical orientation support
- notifyDataSetChanged fully functional

> API changes

- `FragmentStateAdapter` replaces `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
- `RecyclerView.Adapter` replaces `PagerAdapter`
- `registerOnPageChangeCallback` replaces `addPageChangeListener`

**SAMPLE CODE**

> add the latest **`dependencies`** for `ViewPager2`

```
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

> layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    MyAdapter MyAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        arrayList.add("Item 1");
        arrayList.add("Item 2");
        arrayList.add("Item 3");
        arrayList.add("Item 4");
        arrayList.add("Item 5");

        MyAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);


        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);

        myViewPager2.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
    }
}
```

> MyAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        }
    }
}
```

### New features

> now we need to use **`ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback()`** to get Swipe event of `ViewPager2`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);

            Log.e("Selected_Page", String.valueOf(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });
```

> we can set Orientation using `myViewPager2.setOrientation()`

**SAMPLE CODE**

For `HORIZONTAL Orientation` use

```
myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
```

For `VERTICAL Orientation` use

```
myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

> We can use **`notifyDataSetChanged`** same as we are using in `RecyclerView.Adapter`

**SAMPLE CODE to add new item**

```
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            arrayList.add("New ITEM ADDED");
            MyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

**SAMPLE CODE to remove new item**

```
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            arrayList.remove(3);
            MyAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(3);
        }
    });
```

## UPDATE

### Try this if you want to use `Fragment` with `ViewPager2`

> First create a **`ViewPagerFragmentAdapter`** class which extends **`FragmentStateAdapter`**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        arrayList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}
```

> Now use like this in your activity

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
import neel.com.bottomappbar.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    ViewPagerFragmentAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        myAdapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // add Fragments in your ViewPagerFragmentAdapter class
        myAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new Fragmenttwo());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree());

        // set Orientation in your ViewPager2
        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);

        myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }

}
```

for more information check this

- [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)
- [ViewPager2 under the Hood](https://helw.net/2019/02/08/viewpager2-under-the-hood/)
- [Hands on With ViewPager2](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2019/02/07/hands-on-with-viewpager2/)

### UPDATE 2

> [**Version 1.0.0-alpha02**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha02)

**New features**

- Ability to disable user input (`setUserInputEnabled`, `isUserInputEnabled`)

**API changes**

- `ViewPager2` class final

**Bug fixes**

- `FragmentStateAdapter` stability fixes

**SAMPLE CODE to disable swiping in viewpager2**

```
myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);// SAMPLE CODE to disable swiping in viewpager2


myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);//SAMPLE CODE to enable swiping in viewpager2
```

### UPDATE 3

> **[Version 1.0.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha03)**
>
> New features

- Ability to programmatically scroll ViewPager2: **fakeDragBy(offsetPx)**.

> API changes

- `FragmentStateAdapter` now requires a `Lifecycle` object. Two utility constructors added to obtain it from the host `FragmentActivity` or the host Fragment

**SAMPLE CODE**

> ViewPagerFragmentAdapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        arrayList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}
```

> MainActivity code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
import neel.com.bottomappbar.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    ViewPagerFragmentAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myViewPager2=findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        myAdapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

        // add Fragments in your ViewPagerFragmentAdapter class
        myAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new Fragmenttwo());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree());

        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);

        myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 4

> [**`Version 1.0.0-alpha05`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#androidx-deps)
>   New features

- `ItemDecorator` introduced with a behaviour consistent with `RecyclerView`.
- `MarginPageTransformer` introduced to provide an ability to create space between pages (outside of page inset).
- `CompositePageTransformer` introduced to provide an ability to combine multiple `PageTransformers`

> API changes

- `FragmentStateAdapter#getItem` method renamed to `FragmentStateAdapter#createFragment` - previous method name has proven to be a source of bugs in the past.
- `OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT` value changed from 0 to -1. No need for a client code change if the `OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULTconstant` used.

**SAMPLE CODE**

> Activity code

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.MarginPageTransformer;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
import neel.com.bottomappbar.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    ViewPagerFragmentAdapter myAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.myViewPager2);

        // add Fragments in your ViewPagerFragmentAdapter class
        arrayList.add(new FragmentOne());
        arrayList.add(new Fragmenttwo());
        arrayList.add(new FragmentThree());

        myAdapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        // set Orientation in your ViewPager2
        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

        myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        myViewPager2.setPageTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(1500));


    }
}
```

> ViewPagerFragmentAdapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new Fragmenttwo();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like I have to make blog post :D

Comment: Awesome, I didn't get time for blogpost but I will do for sure.

Comment: @PratikButani we have new updates for `ViewPager2` using `Version 1.0.0-alpha02`

Comment: Every time when I read you comment, again refreshing me to write blog :D

Comment: [Early Introduction of ViewPager2](https://blog.usejournal.com/early-introduction-of-viewpager2-ff38c60d2169) by @BirjuVachhani , check this, it might be useful

Comment: Nice detailed description for ViewPager2, 
But please make a edit for, this version of ViewPager2 is released for Android X Only. so you need to add Android X dependecy to compile the project successfully.

Comment: Is it possible to use `PagerTitleStrip` or  `PagerTabStrip` with ViewPager2 or maybe there is an alternative?

Comment: Hi @NileshRathod. In update 4, is there a way to use `ArrayList<Fragment>` object to create fragments dynamically in `ViewPagerFragmentAdapter`?

Comment: @mrisek yes that is possible please [contact me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod?tab=profile) i will send u sample code

Comment: how to slide automatically with indicator ?

Comment: @MahmoudAyman check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518240/7666442

Comment: How to destroy views like `PagerAdapter`'s `destroyItem` function in the custom `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Comment: I tried overriding `onViewRecycled` as `override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
        (holder.itemView as ViewGroup).removeAllViews()
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    }`
it worked

Comment: @PhaniRithvij no need to destroyItem inside `RecyclerView.Adapter` why you want to destroy item inside it ?

Comment: Because I'm getting multiple views laid on top of each other. As I'm doing a `holder.view.addView(view_c)` in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Wouldn't the list of fragments you have in `ViewPagerFragmentAdapter` prevent recycling?

Comment: How to wrap height of Android ViewPager2 to height of current item?

Comment: I think you are still using the old adapter as the new adapter is FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: @AmirDora nop, I haven't updated my answer after Nov 25 '2019

Comment: Please update it, because the new lifecycle feature BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT can be used only with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: why getItem to return Fragment no exist anymore?

Comment: Hi @NileshRathod, it is possible to create ViewPager2 inside a Fragment that can host other Fragments instead of using Activity?

Comment: @Ali yes that's possible

Comment: I have trouble injecting viewPage2 in my fragment which is basically homeFrag, lemme debug my code and figure what I'm missing. Thanks @NileshRathod

Comment: @Ali I am using viewpager with TabLayout in fragment, I am not able to swipe the screen. it's stuck on 1st fragment, how can I solve this issue

Comment: @kdblue have you tred to set the viewpager.isUserInputEnabled = true

Comment: @Ali I solved, it was happening because of swipe refresh layout.

Comment: @iamkdblue i am also facing the same issue, but i wanna keep the swipe refresh layout, do u have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Ali viewpager.isUserInoutEnabled isn't working for me

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod I also have a viewpager2 and tablyout inside a fragment but it isn't swiping.

Comment: @Aldor can you please share your code let me check your code

Comment: @Aldor which artifact version you're using in your app build.gradle dependency?

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod here is the link to my question. I have the code there as well . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810129/viewpager2-with-tablayout-inside-a-fragment-shows-no-swipe-effect-in-kotlin

Comment: @Ali implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"

Comment: @NileshRathod, you have created an arraylist of fragments but you're not calling them anywhere?

Comment: nice and detailed post but can u add how to handle lifecycles in viewpager2 as I am not able to find any solution.. ?

Comment: All answers are here, thanks a lot,I wish the google documentation team can pick a leaf of how an API migration manual ought to look like

Comment: That's a lot of knowledge for such a thing, I'm missing a simple TabLayout constructor where you can simply pass the array of fragments with titles and be done.

Comment: @AskNilesh how can I give you more point sir

Comment: In the last example ViewPagerFragmentAdapter has an arraylist but it's not used. Can we do return arraylist[position] in createFragment() ?

Comment: @MuhammadHanzilah Yes you can

Answer (score 14):

Actually now there is an official samples repo for ViewPager2 (linked below)

- https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2

Repo contains following samples (Quoting from the repo readme below)

> **Samples**
>
> - ViewPager2 with Views - shows how to set up a ViewPager2 with Views    as pages
> - ViewPager2 with Fragments - shows how to set up a ViewPager2    with Fragments as pages
> - ViewPager2 with a Mutable Collection (Views) - demonstrates usage of ViewPager2 with Views as pages and mutations in a page adapter
> - ViewPager2 with a Mutable Collection (Fragments) -    demonstrates usage of ViewPager2 with Fragments as pages, and    mutations in a
>     page adapter
> - ViewPager2 with a TabLayout (Views) -    shows how to set up a ViewPager2 with Views as pages, and link it to    a TabLayout

---

**Simple example of ViewPager2 with Fragments in Kotlin**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager2_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val viewPager2 = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.pager2_container)

        val fragmentList = arrayListOf(
            FirstFragment.newInstance(),
            SecondFragment.newInstance(),
            ThirdFragment.newInstance()
        )
        viewPager2.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this, fragmentList)
   }
}
```

**FirstFragment.kt** (`SecondFragment.kt` and `ThirdFragment.kt` looks similar to `FirstFragment.kt`)

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    companion object{
        fun newInstance() = FirstFragment()
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter.kt**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fa:FragmentActivity, private val fragments:ArrayList<Fragment>): FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragments.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = fragments[position]

}
```

---

**Some other useful resources:**

- API reference:
  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2
- Training: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2
- Release notes: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2
- Medium article by a GDE : [Exploring the ViewPager2](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-view-pager-2-86dbce06ff71)

Comment: How can we use this type of implementation with ViewBinding?

Comment: @MaulikDodia nothing special is needed use as usual, please see the docs : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 7):

> Use of ViewPager2 in Android

As mentioned on [Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha01)

**API changes**

> FragmentStateAdapter replaces FragmentStatePagerAdapter
>
> RecyclerView.Adapter replaces PagerAdapter
>
> registerOnPageChangeCallback replaces addPageChangeListener

**In Simple Words they make it View Pager adapter work like Recycle View Adapter.**

Note:- We don't need to use fragment in View Pager 2. It is fully depend on RecyclerView.Adapter inflate layout.

Here is sample gitHub repo [Link](https://github.com/sushildlh/ViewPager2)

Example:-

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private ViewPager2 mPager;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("View Pager 2");
        mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyViewPagerAdapter(this));
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (R.id.change == item.getItemId()) {
            mPager.setOrientation(mPager.getOrientation() != ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL ? ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL : ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> MyViewPagerAdapter.class

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {
    
    private Context context;
    
    public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }
    
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cell_item, parent, false));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.mText.setText("Page "+(position+1));
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

> cell_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Page 1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> MyHolder.class

```
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
    public TextView mText;
    
    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Can not we use ViewPager2 with fragments?

Comment: @ysfcyln yes you can use `Fragment` with `ViewPager2` please check [my above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54643817/7666442) i  have added sample code for  `How use Fragment with ViewPager2`

Comment: Thanks, but the repository is deleted.

Comment: @CoolMind Which repository  is deleted?

Comment: https://github.com/sushildlh/ViewPager2. See also https://medium.com/swlh/android-viewpager2-tablayout-3099aae2f396 for new info. :)

Comment: Here is the repo -> https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did to implemet ViewPager2 with TabLayout with 3 Fragment full Examble:

Layout  contains `ViewPager2` with `TabLayout`:

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include3">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_dismiss_color"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/green"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#e4e4e4" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

init ViewPager2 and set Tabs Name:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        actionBarTitleId.setText(R.string.reports);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(this));

        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, (tab, position) -> {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tab.setText(R.string.financial_duty_str);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tab.setText(R.string.financial_unpaid_str);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tab.setText(R.string.financial_paid_str);
                    break;

            }
        }).attach();

    }
```

`ViewPager2` adapter :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {


    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FinancialFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FinancialUnPaidFragment();
            case 2:
                return new FinancialPaidFragment();
            default:
                return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
```

dependency used:

```
implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

Comment: How did you solve switching between tabs? For example when I chose 1 then 1 and 2 is loaded. Somehow skips from 1 to 2...

Answer (score 2):

How to use it explained very clearly. Let me give small but very crucial tips and details about ViewPager2 especially if it's inside a fragment about how to prevent memory leaks

1. Don't use the constructor that takes fragment especially if you are using `TabLayout`.

   ```
   public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
       this(fragment.getChildFragmentManager(), fragment.getLifecycle());
   }
   ```

because it has risk of memory leak as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62184494/5457853)

instead use the one takes FragmentManager and LifeCycle. And don't send `lifeCycle` of fragment as argument, use `viewLifeCycleOwner`'s lifecycle because viewLifeCycleOwner represents life cycle of fragment's `view`.

```
 class NavigableFragmentStateAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {


}
```

and set adapter with in `onCreateView`

```
viewPager.adapter =
            NavigableFragmentStateAdapter(childFragmentManager, viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)
```

2. If you are using `TabLayout` when ViewPager2 is inside a fragment do not forget to detach TabLayout and set adapter of ViewPager2 as

detach TabLayoutMediator since it causing memory leaks when it's in a fragment

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779776/leak-canary-detects-memory-leaks-for-tablayout-with-viewpager2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851425/viewpager2-inside-a-fragment-leaks-after-replacing-the-fragment-its-in-by-navig)

[ViewPager2 inside a fragment leaks after replacing the fragment it's in by Navigation Component navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851425/viewpager2-inside-a-fragment-leaks-after-replacing-the-fragment-its-in-by-navig)

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, tabConfigurationStrategy).detach()     
viewPager2.adapter = null
```

inside `onDestroyView` method of Fragment

3. If you wish to use pages of ViewPager as `navHostFragment` with navigation components to navigate back to child fragments register FragmentTransactionCallback in `FragmentStateAdapter` as

   ```
   private val fragmentTransactionCallback =
       object : FragmentStateAdapter.FragmentTransactionCallback() {
           override fun onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated(
               fragment: Fragment,
               maxLifecycleState: Lifecycle.State
           ) = if (maxLifecycleState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {

               // This fragment is becoming the active Fragment - set it to
               // the primary navigation fragment in the OnPostEventListener
               OnPostEventListener {
                   fragment.parentFragmentManager.commitNow {
                       setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment)
                   }
               }
           } else {
               super.onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated(fragment, maxLifecycleState)
           }
       }

   init {
       // Add a FragmentTransactionCallback to handle changing
       // the primary navigation fragment
       registerFragmentTransactionCallback(fragmentTransactionCallback)
   }
   ```

Also if you wish to see some samples how to use ViewPager2 with navigation components, dynamic feature modules and combining with BottomNavigationView you can check out the tutorials [in this github repo.](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/NavigationComponents-Tutorials)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case one may want to listen for `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback` events:

```
private final ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

    /**
     * This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled, either as part
     * of a programmatically initiated smooth scroll or a user initiated touch scroll.
     * @param position             Position index of the first page currently being displayed.
     *                             Page position+1 will be visible if positionOffset is nonzero.
     * @param positionOffset       Value from [0, 1) indicating the offset from the page at position.
     * @param positionOffsetPixels Value in pixels indicating the offset from position.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    }

    /**
     * This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
     * Animation is not necessarily complete.
     * @param position             Position index of the first page currently being displayed.
     *                             Page position+1 will be visible if positionOffset is nonzero.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected (int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        if (position == 2) { // SomeFragment
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ViewPager2.onPageSelected( " + position + " )");
            SomePagerAdapter adapter = (SomePagerAdapter) viewpager.getAdapter();
            if (adapter != null) {
                SomeFragment fragment = (SomeFragment) adapter.getItem(position);
                fragment.onLateInit();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To be applied with `ViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback()`:

```
viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(this.onPageChangeListener);
```

The `FragmentStateAdapter` needs to hold an `ArrayList<Fragment> mItems`, so that one can access the instances, which are being constructed ahead of time. `SomeFragment` exposes method `public void onLateInit()`, because `@Override public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)` can possibly not be used (depends on the `Fragment`).

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.mItems.get(position);
}
```

---

Alike this one one work around the issue, what the `Fragment` is being constructed long before one might be able to properly initialize it's view, eg. with data entered in the previous one `Fragment`. It might not be the optimum for a large amount of `Fragment` (...), but for a few it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

here is kotlin version implementation of @sushildlh answer in Kotlin.
in this code I am implementing viewpager2 with recyclerview to view images.
also i am using viewbinding

food_details.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.recipeitem.RecipeDetailsFragment">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />
...
```

the fragment which inflates this xml

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RecipeDetailsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_recipe_details) {

private val viewModel: RecipeItemViewModel by viewModels()
private val viewBinding: FragmentRecipeDetailsBinding by viewBinding()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    bindRecipeData(//object of data that is to be desplayed)
}

private fun bindRecipeData(recipeDetailedInfo: RecipeDetailedInfo?) {
    recipeDetailedInfo?.let {
        with(viewBinding) {
            viewPager2.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(it.images)
            viewPager2.setPageTransformer(ZoomOutPageTransformer())
            lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                delay(500)
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(if (it.images.size >= 2) 1 else 0, true)
            }
        }
    }
}....
```

in the fragment i am creating object of the adapter and sending directly list of strings that contains the images URLs

here is the viewpager adapter which is basically a normal recyclerview adapter

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.blogspot.soyamr.recipes2.databinding.ImageviewBinding
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class ViewPagerAdapter(private val images: List<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ImageViewHolder>() {


    class ImageViewHolder(private val imageViewBinding: ImageviewBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(imageViewBinding.root) {
        fun bind(imageLink: String) {
            Picasso.get().load(imageLink).into(imageViewBinding.root)
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ImageViewHolder {
                val itemBinding =
                    ImageviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
                return ImageViewHolder(itemBinding)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageViewHolder {
        return ImageViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(images[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = images.size

}
```

in the recyclerview i am inflating this imageview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:theme="@style/roundedImageView"
    />
```

you use your complex xml view if needed

Answer (score 1):

Simple example with two differente fragments, usin tabs. Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainTabLayout">

    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:background="@color/brown_normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/yellow_light"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/yellow_light"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/yellow_normal"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
public class MainToolsAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
{
    // The quantity of tab is fixed
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 2;
    // Titles for each tab    
    private final String[] titles = new String[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

    public MainToolsAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle, Context context)
    {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        // Load titles for tab from resourses
        titles[0] = context.getResources().getString(R.string.tab_1);
        titles[1] = context.getResources().getString(R.string.tab_2);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position)
    {
        // Create fragments according to position
        if(position == 0)
        {
            return new FragmentTabOne();
        }
        return new FragmentTabTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
    }

    public String getItemTitle(int position)
    {
        if(position == 0)
        {
            return titles[0];
        }
        return titles[1];
    }
}
```

Main activity OnCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create adapter for ViewPager
    mainToolsAdapter = new MainToolsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle(), this);

    // Set adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.mainViewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mainToolsAdapter);

    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainTabLayout);

    // Create the TabLayoutMediator to asociate ViewPager2 to TabLayout
    TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, true, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy()
    {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position)
        {
            // When a tab is created this is called, then we can set tab properties, in this case the text
            tab.setText(mainToolsAdapter.getItemTitle(position));
        }
    });
    // After configure we need to realice attach then Tab and ViewPager2 are asociated
    tabLayoutMediator.attach();
}
```

gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.yyyy"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies
{
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code, with no explanation! Some comments and/or supporting text would be useful especially to help people understand, and derive their own solutions

Comment: @andrew I added more comments to the code for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution (Android Studio 3.6):

In app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.3'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta05'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Here my activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.myproject.android.R;
import com.myproject.android.adapter.CustomFragmentStateAdapter;
import com.myproject.android.ui.fragment.BluetoothPageFragment;
import com.myproject.android.ui.fragment.QrPageFragment;

public class QRBluetoothSwipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    private CustomFragmentStateAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Make sure this is before calling super.onCreate
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme); // show splash screen
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qr_bluetooth_swipe_activity);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        QrPageFragment m1 = new QrPageFragment();
        BluetoothPageFragment m2 = new BluetoothPageFragment();
        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        fragmentList.add(m2);
        fragmentList.add(m1);
        myAdapter = new CustomFragmentStateAdapter(this, fragmentList);
        myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.actviity.SplashDelayActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here my **CustomFragmentStateAdapter**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomFragmentStateAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> listFragment = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomFragmentStateAdapter(FragmentActivity fa, List<Fragment> list) {
        super(fa);
        listFragment = list;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return listFragment.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

And here my fragments:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.myproject.android.R;

public class BluetoothPageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bluetooth_page_fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

and second fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.myproject.android.R;

public class QrPageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.qr_page_fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

And as result now I use `androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2` with my custom fragments.

And it's work!!!

Nice.

P.S. Another implement:

```
public class CustomFragmentStateAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomFragmentStateAdapter (FragmentActivity fa) {
        super(fa);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        arrayList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        // return your fragment that corresponds to this 'position'
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }
}
```

And use like this (in activity):

```
 myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        myAdapter = new CustomFragmentStateAdapter (this);
        myAdapter.addFragment(new QrPageFragment());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new BluetoothPageFragment());
        myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: I have used it, with recyclerview of images inside FragmentPageAdapter and its too slow as a pig running with horses.

Comment: This is **not** correct. `createFragment` callback of the `FragmentStateAdapter` should (as the method says) **`create`** a `Fragment`. And not give a one that has already been created and is lying around. By using your approach you're messing up with `FragmentManager's` operation.

Comment: @BartekLipinski. So how i "can dynamically modify the fragment collection at runtime, and ViewPager2 will correctly display the modified collection." as [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#modifiable-fragments) say?

Comment: @BartekLipinski, I created a list of 4 fragments and then in `createFragment` returned an item by position. Everything works as expected, no need to recreate a fragment each time. But the adapter is called this way: `val adapter = object : FragmentStateAdapter(childFragmentManager, viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)`.

Comment: Just the fact that it "works as expected", doesn't mean that it "works as it should". `FragmentManager` is quite a complex piece of machinery (~4k lines of code) and by not following its API, you **might** experience some edge-cases and uncertain behavior.

Comment: I am doin the same but I noticed some duplication of fragment on orientation change if I use viewpager.setCurrentItem(savedIndex) in onCreate() . Did anyone face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I first created a view pager, then migrated to view pager 2 using the instructions given in:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Answer (score 0):

**This is the correct implementation!**

```
typealias FragmentBuilder = () -> Fragment

class MyAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager, 
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    private val fragmentBuilders = mutableListOf<FragmentBuilder>()

    fun add(fragmentBuilder: FragmentBuilder) {
        fragmentBuilders.add(fragmentBuilder)
    }

    /**
     * Dynamic replacement of fragments
     */
    fun set(position: Int, fragmentBuilder: FragmentBuilder) {
        fragmentBuilders[position] = fragmentBuilder
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = fragmentBuilders.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int) = fragmentBuilders[position].invoke()

}
```

Don't even thank)

Comment: can u help me with lifecycle implementation as I am not able to find any resource regarding handling lifecycles.....

Answer (score 0):

**In Kotlin FragmentStateAdapter with ViewPager2**
*The primary reason to migrate is that ViewPager2 is receiving active development support and ViewPager is not. However, ViewPager2 also offers several other specific advantages.*
*FragmentStateAdapter in ViewPager2 is a little bit different than in ViewPager as follows:
1] Instead of implementing getCount(), implement getItemCount()
2] Instead of implementing getItem(int position), implement createFragment(int position)
3] Constructor signature is different by adding Lifecycle argument which should be included in super as well
So replace your ViewPagerFragmentAdapter with below*

**Kotlin PagerAdapter**

```
class SurveyPagerAdapter(
private val fragmentList: MutableList< Fragment>,
fragment: FragmentManager,
lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment,lifecycle){
override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragmentList.size
override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragmentList[position]
}
fun getFragmentName(position: Int) = fragmentList[position]
fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}}
```

**Kotlin Activity**
*Just put on method in onCreate() *

```
private fun setUpViewPager(){

    val fragmentList : MutableList< Fragment> = mutableListOf()
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageOneFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageTwoFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageThreeFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageFourFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageFiveFragment.newInstance(true))

    surveyPagerAdapter = SurveyPagerAdapter(fragmentList,supportFragmentManager,lifecycle)
    binding.viewPager.adapter = surveyPagerAdapter
    binding.dotsIndicator.attachTo(binding.viewPager)

}
```

**Kotlin Fragment**

```
class SurveyPageOneFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
    }
}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_survey_page_one, container, false)
}
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(isMyBoolean: Boolean) = SurveyPageOneFragment().apply {
        val fragment = SurveyPageOneFragment()
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putBoolean("REPLACE WITH A STRING CONSTANT", isMyBoolean)
        }
        fragment.arguments
        return fragment
    }
}}
```

**xml code in viewPager2**

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"/>
```

**Dot indicator**
*lib*`//kotlin dot indicator implementation 'com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:4.3'`

```
<com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.DotsIndicator
                android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:dotsColor="@color/colorSurveyEditGreenLight"
                app:dotsCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:dotsSize="16dp"
                app:dotsSpacing="4dp"
                app:dotsWidthFactor="2.5"
                app:selectedDotColor="@color/white"
                app:progressMode="true"
                />
```

Answer (score -2):

I personally used ViewPager2 inside of a Fragment. This is how I do it. Example code on GitHub [https://github.com/codebyjames/Example-Using-ViewPager2-Slide-Page-Adapter]

First in onCreate

```
        // pager adapter
        val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePageAdapter(this@ManagerFragment)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(ZoomOutPageTransformer())
```

Adapter for the ViewPager

```
class ScreenSlidePageAdapter(val fragment: Fragment): FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

val fragments = listOf(WalkThroughFragment(), PermissionsFragment(), DatastoreFragment())

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fragments.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragments[position]
}
```

}

Transformation for ViewPager2 - optional

```
class ZoomOutPageTransformer : ViewPager2.PageTransformer {

override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {
    view.apply {
        val pageWidth = width
        val pageHeight = height
        when {
            position < -1 -> { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                alpha = 0f
            }
            position <= 1 -> { // [-1,1]
                // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
                val scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position))
                val vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2
                val horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2
                translationX = if (position < 0) {
                    horzMargin - vertMargin / 2
                } else {
                    horzMargin + vertMargin / 2
                }

                // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
                scaleX = scaleFactor
                scaleY = scaleFactor

                // Fade the page relative to its size.
                alpha = (MIN_ALPHA +
                        (((scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) / (1 - MIN_SCALE)) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA)))
            }
            else -> { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                alpha = 0f
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

My ManagerFragment layout (which contains the ViewPager2)

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```