# How to use VerticalViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

I want to use a vertical slide on my application so i implemented this library:
https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager
by adding `implementation com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1` 
in the dependencies of build.gradle.

Now i want to add this viewPager to my xml file (If it was native horizontal View pager i'll do in the layout something like `<android.support.v4.ViewPager>`)
But everything i try failed, what is the syntax to do it ? (never worked with libraries before)
I've tried   `<github.castorflex.verticalviewpager>` too
Thanks

Comment: You can use [**`ViewPager2`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) check here from demo https://stackoverflow.com/a/54643817/7666442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put in your xml

```
<fr.castorflex.android.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager
        android:id="@+id/verticalviewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```