# Tiktok like video scrolling

Tags: video, scroll, android-viewpager, transition

I want to load the list of videos where the scroll should be like tiktok scrolling, I have used vertical viewpager to load each video in different pages and using texturevideo view,when page changed stop video and start the current focused video,likewise for other videos, but I am not getting the proper output, Please provide any solution to achieve it.

Thanks in Advance.

```
     @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("PAGER",position + "");
            mCurrentFragmentPosition = position;

            if (lastPosition > position) {
              Log.e("Up",position+"");
              Log.e("lastPosition",lastPosition+"");
```

//                  customAdapter.fastVideoViews.get(position).start();
                    customAdapter.fastVideoViews.get(lastPosition).pause();

```
            }else if (lastPosition < position) {
                Log.e("Down",position+"");
                Log.e("lastPosition",lastPosition+"");
```

//                    customAdapter.fastVideoViews.get(position).start();
                    customAdapter.fastVideoViews.get(lastPosition).pause();

```
            }
            lastPosition = position;



            customAdapter.fastVideoViews.get(position).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: ViewPager2 [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2] is perfect solution of your video scrolling.

Comment: @TusharLathiya the page you referred showing 404 error, the page is unavailable.

Comment: Akash link belongs to official documentation of ViewPager2. Instead of ViewPager use ViewPager2. VideoView is enough for playing short videos. just create new fragment instance for every video. thats it.

Comment: @TusharLathiya thanks for you answer i'll try this.

Comment: @TusharLathiya the link you have provided is not available anymore. Can you provide some code to me.

Comment: Sorry Akash I can suggest you ideas. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643379/use-of-viewpager2-in-android