# ViewPager2 swipe only once on a single swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I want to have ViewPager stop capturing swipe events that are outside of the ViewPager container so that the user can never scroll by more than one page during a single swipe like TikTok.
If you swipe Tiktok video without release touch(take two fingers and keep scroll) it will not allow to play next video.

What i did :

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                if (state == SCROLL_INDICATOR_END) {
                    viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what you are trying to achieve? As far as i know you can only swipe ViewPager to next or previous page with one swipe. You need to release touch and swipe again if you want to see another page.

Comment: Yeah, the same here. What is the problem with simple `ViewPager`?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Want to make video player like Tiktok. Please take a look how Tiktok app playing videos, you will get my question properly. Just take to finger and keep swipe. they will not allow to play next video.

Comment: @GensaGames have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643379/use-of-viewpager2-in-android

Comment: @TusharLathiya, did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @RamachandraReddyAvula have a look [here] (https://github.com/YoKeyword/Fragmentation)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a RecylcerView instead of a viewpager and a StartSnapHelper to achieve this effect.

https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8