# Why FragmentStateAdapter not work in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

Android Studio 3.6

I want in my activity to use 2 fragments inside ViewPager2.

Here my activity:

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
public class QRBluetoothSwipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    private ViewPagerFragmentAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Make sure this is before calling super.onCreate
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme); // show splash screen
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.qr_bluetooth_swipe_activity);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        myAdapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new BluetoothPageFragment());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new QrPageFragment());
        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
        myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

}
```

here ViewPagerFragmentAdapter

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter  extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        arrayList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}
```

but I get compile error:

```
ViewPagerFragmentAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method createFragment(int) in FragmentStateAdapter
```

How I can fix this and use **FRAGMENTS** in **ViewPager2** ?

Thanks

Comment: This solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987690/viewpager2-reuse-fragments-when-popbackstack-is-called/72538430#72538430

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`FragmentStateAdapter` in `ViewPager2` is a little bit different than in `ViewPager` as follows:

- Instead of implementing `getCount()`, implement `getItemCount()`
- Instead of implementing `getItem(int position)`, implement `createFragment(int position)`
- Constructor signature is different by adding `Lifecycle` argument
  which should be included in super as well

So replace your `ViewPagerFragmentAdapter` with below

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        arrayList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        // return your fragment that corresponds to this 'position'
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

}
```

Also make sure to import/extend the right adapter of ViewPager2

```
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;
```

### UPDATE 2021

This answered the original issue of the question; However creating the `FragmentStateAdapter` this way is not that right generally speaking; because of:

1. To have a high performant `ViewPager`, it should keep only a few instantiated off-screen page fragments.
2. Keeping all the page fragments into a list is not good in terms of wasting device resources.
3. `createFragment()`, as its name implies, is intended to create a new fragment for a particular page and return it; not to return a fragment from a list that has already instantiated fragments.
4. Above all [as per documentation createFragment():](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter#createfragment):

> Provide a new Fragment associated with the specified position.
>
> The adapter will be responsible for the Fragment lifecycle:
>
> - The Fragment will be used to display an item.
> - The Fragment will be destroyed when it gets too far from the
>   viewport, and its state will be saved. When the item is close to the
>   viewport again, a new Fragment will be requested, and a previously
>   saved state will be used to initialize it.

So, I'd suggest to change this design to include that into consideration:

Assuming your page fragment is `PageFragment`; then you can have single instance pattern by having `static PageFragment newInstance(int position) {}` method in the `PageFragment`, and then the `createFragment()` should be then:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    // return a brand new fragment that corresponds to this 'position'
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position); // Create a new instance of the page fragment
}
```

Comment: I found solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643379/use-of-viewpager2-in-android/58527394#58527394

Comment: Use this constructor:  public ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
        super(fa);
    }

Comment: @a_subscriber thanks for this tip, it works as well

Comment: This is a *VERY* wrong implementation. As naming imply, FragmentStateAdapter's `createFragment` should be responsible for instantiate Fragment. Creation of Fragment shouldn't happen outside `FragmentStateAdapter`. `FragmentStateAdapter` will be responsible for handling memory usage efficiency, even you need to create a large number of Fragments. If you create Fragment outside `FragmentStateAdapter`, it is highly not memory efficiency.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng So how i "can dynamically modify the fragment collection at runtime, and ViewPager2 will correctly display the modified collection." as [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#modifiable-fragments) say?

Comment: I have the similar requirement where I need to add/remove/move/modify Fragments. I believe you need to override `getItemId` and `containsItem` correctly. I still in the midway of testing `viewpager2`. I will confirm with you whether my provided info is correct, after I finished with all testing.

Comment: What is purpose of overriding "containsItem" and "getItemId"? Are these overrides required if one is passing in new lists to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter implementation and calling notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng What is purpose of overriding "containsItem" and "getItemId"? Are these overrides required if one is passing in new lists to the FragmentStatePagerAdapter implementation and calling notifyDataSetChanged? Asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382901/what-is-purpose-of-overriding-containsitem-and-getitemid-in-fragmentstatead

Comment: @all I've enhanced the answer to be more efficient like it should be