# What is purpose of overriding `containsItem` and `getItemId` in `FragmentStateAdapter`?

Tags: android, androidx, fragmentstateadapter

What is purpose of overriding `containsItem` and `getItemId` in `FragmentStateAdapter`?

Are these overrides required if one is passing in new lists to the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` implementation and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`?

From the doc, appears both overrides are require if the underlying data set is changing, and you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged`?

```
/**
 * Default implementation works for collections that don't add, move, remove items.
 * <p>
 * TODO(b/122670460): add lint rule
 * When overriding, also override {@link #getItemId(int)}
 */
public boolean containsItem(long itemId) {
    return itemId >= 0 && itemId < getItemCount();
}

/**
 * Default implementation works for collections that don't add, move, remove items.
 * <p>
 * TODO(b/122670460): add lint rule
 * When overriding, also override {@link #containsItem(long)}.
 * <p>
 * If the item is not a part of the collection, return {@link RecyclerView#NO_ID}.
 *
 * @param position Adapter position
 * @return stable item id {@link RecyclerView.Adapter#hasStableIds()}
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

So for example, here is my implementation

```
class MyAdapter(host : Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(host) {

    data class FragItem(val newInstance : () -> Fragment, val fragId : Long)

    private var fragments = mapOf<Integer,FragItem>()

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]?.newInstance?.invoke() ?: DefaultFragment()
    }
    
    fun applyDataSet(newFragments : Map<Integer, FragItem>) {
        fragments = newFragments
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = fragments.size

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean{
        return fragments.any { it.value.fragId == itemId }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) : Long{
        return fragments.values.elementAt(position).fragId
    }
}
```

Now can I get rid of `getItemId` and `containsItem`? Or leave them? What about `getItemCount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `getItemCount` will instruct the recycler how many items are to be rendered. the current index will be passed as `position` to `createFragment`, so clearly you need it
- the `getItemId` and `containsItem` implemented if you want to provide stable ID's for your  recycler. having stable ID's allows for a certain optimisations to be made, usually when it involves operations on elements that are not next to each-other in the list.

Comment: I think you're right, here is a good case study: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2lr8bf/what_does_recyclerview_sethasstableids_do_and_why/