# How to use PagerTabStrip with ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, pagertabstrip

I want to use `ViewPager2` because it is supposed to replace `ViewPager` and I hope to get rid of some problems I've had with `ViewPager`.

I want to do this:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/detail_pager_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/detail_pager_strip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
```

But `ViewPager2` complains that it cannot have any children. On the other hand, if I move `PagerTabStrip` out of `ViewPager2` it complains that it must be a child of a `ViewPager`.

So it seems that `PagerTabStrip` is not compatible with `ViewPager2`. Am I correct?

Is there any current solution to this? (except writing your own `PagerTabStrip`)

Comment: no solution found?

Comment: @PavelPoley: I ended up implementing PagerTabStrip functionality myself.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to this, you need to use TabLayout

[Use of ViewPager2 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643379/use-of-viewpager2-in-android)

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabs"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```