# How to use PagerTitleStrip in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, pagertitlestrip

I have a standard implementation of `PagerTitleStrip` in `ViewPager` but it cannot work in `ViewPager2`. If I want to migrate to `ViewPager2`, how should I implement `PagerTitleStrip` within `ViewPager2`? I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065972/how-to-use-pagertabstrip-with-viewpager2) and many [detailed info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643379/use-of-viewpager2-in-android) regarding how to implement `PagerTabStrip` behaviour using `TabLayout` but it is not applicable to `PagerTitleStrip`.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager2` based on `RecyclerView` and implement only a limited subset of old `ViewPager` features.

Currently you cannot properly use neither `PagerTitleStrip` nor `PagerTabStrip` with `ViewPager2`.

Frankly I don't even know usecase where `TabLayout` with custom themed tabs and indicator and, maybe, some little extra code won't suffice.

Thus the only solution for `ViewPager2` as for now is to use `TabLayout`.

Maybe if you will ask a question in context of your usecase or needed design - there will be a more detailed answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "TabLayout with custom themed tabs and indicator and, maybe, some little extra code won't suffice." How isn't that a problem? I wanted to switch to ViewPager2 because it is simplier and more powerful, so it defeat the whole purpose of the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ViewPager2 has many bugs, that should be fix may be in future.
while i was working on same i also found a bug and because of that i am unable to use ViewPager2 properly.
For now it should be good if you use ViewPager only and avoid to use ViewPager2 for some time.
Or the suggestion of Paul Ost is also good and acceptable.