# How to achieve vertical sliding views UI for android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I know it's a card view may be in a Recycler View

[image: View Image Here]

Update:

this is what I could achieve so far:

the recyclerview:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

card view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_card_label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1231231 2123123 12313 "/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the recyclerview code:

```
            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new CatalogAdapter(list);

        mAdapter.ItemClick += MAdapter_ItemClick;

        PagerSnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.AttachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and this is the result:
[UI Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLgJG.gif)

the question is what is the idea behind the  expanding animation in the begining of the example UI ? 
help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create XML for yourself. This is not an issue here.

1- You can use RecyclerView Snap helper for this. You must make your items full screen and pager snap helper to your recycler view.

```
PagerSnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

2- Alternatively, you can use View Pager 2, it supports vertical paging.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54643817/11982611  explains it in details

Comment: I used the RecyclerView, but how to get the starting animation ?? whta's the idea behind it ?