# How to implement sliding functionality in android app

Tags: java, android

I am Learning android development on my own, I am working on a quiz app, in this app, I want to add 100 questions (1 screen for 1 question)
user can go to the next question by swiping so how can I do it?
should I use 100 fragments for each question with the help of viewpager or any other method is available to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ViewPage2` for swiping.

Comment: ok, but what about fragments, should I add 100 fragments in my project?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643379/proper-implementation-of-viewpager2-in-android